# Where to physically store a VisualSvn branch or trunk to compile

Tags: visual-studio, branch, visualsvn

I'm using Visual SVN with Visual Studio 2010 and want to work on a feature branch of my solution. I've read the [documentation](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/branchmerge/using/) here and [the book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.pdf) regarding branching.  I'm new to Visual SVN and seem to be missing the idea of where I should keep my copies of the files I am using to actually develop and compile the different version of my project.  I understand that to SVN, the repository basically holds "virtual" copies of the files.  Will I need separate local copies so that one folder will contain only those files from the trunk copy and some separate folder will contain the full solution of the branch?

As I understand it, Visual Svn will let me make my local copies wherever I want, but I'm trying to figure out a logical way to do this.  If I have two separate folders with these near-identical versions of my app, won't I have two indistinguishable entries in Visual Studio's start menu?  They would list different paths if I mouse over it I suppose.  Am I missing the point, or do I just feel awkward about the way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think it is only subjective. It was the same for me the first times with SVN, but... 
Checkout in different folders for trunk and branches (naming each folder in a meaningful way)
then create two different desktop shortcut to your different solutions in your different folders and go back to code...